# Mongoose findOne in an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  integrations: {
    discord: {
      guild: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: [20, "Guild ID cannot be longer than 20 characters"],
        required: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Hub", schema);
```

That is my mongoose schema. How do I get a Hub by its guild in integrations.discord.guild when using .findOne

Answer (score 1):

For Query on [Nested Field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field)

```
Hub.findOne({'integrations.discord.guild': '----'})
```

Comment: @donzee529 mark as answered if the answer is useful. upvote will bonus.